# Can I search floats / doubles in IDA?

Tags: ida

I have two versions of the same binary, and I know that both are using a float (`127.0`) which is stored in a variable like `ds:dbl_7F5A28` (offset from binary #1).

There's only one xref to that `dbl_` in both binaries, but I don't know how to find `127.0` in binary #2, so I can xref it and find the function that's using it.

So, is there a way to search for float / double values in IDA?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps at all, but would it be easier to search for the instructions that manipulate floating point values?

Comment: @blahfish I'm analyzing a game, and floating point values are (ab)used a lot, so that wouldn't help

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do this.

1. Text search. Just press Alt-T in the disassembly window and enter 127.0. This will probably not work if in your current idb version this value is not recognized as floating point number.
2. Binary search. Go to the binary where your known value resides, go to the address of this value and undefine it/see its byte contents any other way. You will see the binary representation on the same place. Search it as a binary on the second binary and you'll probably find desirable.

Good luck

Comment: The problem is that the binary is kinda big (200MB+), so text search is really, really slow and not effective. Binary search didn't work (searched for `0x42fe0000` -> `127.0`)

Comment: what does it mean didn't work ? Gave too much alternatives or did not find anything ? Did you try binary search on first executable ?

Comment: Did not find anything, however, I just found the function by xref-ing other known functions, and it does use the number (as I supposed). Therefore, not a reliable way to search for floats.

Comment: Does binary representation looks the same in both executables ?

Comment: It 'does': in one binary it's like `127.0`, in the other one it's in hexadecimal form. I can, of course, make both be `127.0` or `0x42fe0000 ` by redefining the type, but if I need to find it first, there's no way I can do this.

Comment: OK, just to clarify the issue: Open Options-->General and set number of opcode bytes (non-graph) to 8. You'll see binary representation of the value just after its address. Is it representation same in both binaries ?

Comment: @AcidShout: IDA's *representation* of the float does not modify the internal value. You should search for `0x42fe0000`, is what ws is telling you. The problem is that there may be different sequences of bytes that IDA *shows* as `127.0`, because there are lots of floating point formats.